# Using regex, Conditionally replace with $1 or empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a function in javascript which accepts two arguments : a regex object and a string.
The regex can have at most one capturing group.
If there is a capturing group, it shall return $1, otherwise the remaining string;

So `myfunc("hello123", /\d+/)` shall return hello and
`myfunc("hello123", /\w+(\d+)/)` shall return 123

How to identify if there's a capturing group or not?

Comment: In your first example: `myfunc("hello123", /\d+/) shall return hello` ..you are replacing the second argument with nothing and returning the string. In your second example: `myfunc("hello123", /\w+(\d+)/) shall return 123` you are matching and returning match[1]. There has to be a uniform behaviour to build a function on.

Comment: There's a logic :  If there is a capturing group in the regex, it shall return $1, otherwise it shall replace the string with the given pattern. First example : `myfunc("hello123", /\d+/)`, no matching group, so the string matching the given pattern /\d+/ shall be removed. second example `myfunc("hello123", /\w+(\d+)/)`, there's a matching group, so I need the part that matched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `match` if the pattern couldn't be matched at all `null` is returned. If there was a match, the string at index `0` will be the full match while subsequent indexes will contain capturing groups. Basically the first capturing group will be at index `1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
function myfunc(str, re) {
   m = str.match(re);
   if (m && m.length == 2)
      return m[1];
   else
      return str.replace(m[0], '');
}
```

**Testing:**

```
myfunc("hello123", /\d+/);
hello

myfunc("hello123", /\w+?(\d+)/)
123
```

**PS:** Use `m.length` to figure out how many matced groups are there in the regex being passed as argument.

Comment: fails in this case : `myfunc("hello", /\w+?(\d+)/)`

Comment: It returns `123` for that case and that is your expected output also.